# Swift 3 request post , response returns nil

Tags: ios, json, swift, post, request

I have post request and parse response json codes but my codes dont working.

My class codes

```
    @discardableResult
    open func  getLoginMethod(_ method: String, parameters: String, completionHandler: @escaping (_ login: [Login]?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) -> URLSessionTask! {
        let session = URLSession.shared
        guard let url = NSURL(string: parameters) else {
            completionHandler(nil, myErrors.InvalidUrlError)
            return nil
        }

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let sendingdata = "Simple=1"
        request.httpBody = sendingdata.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error in

             if error != nil {
                completionHandler(nil, myErrors.getError)
            } else {
                do {
                    let login = try self.getLogin(jsonData: data! as NSData)

                    print(login)

                    completionHandler(login, nil)
                } catch {
                    completionHandler(nil, error)
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()

        return task
    }
```

And when i click to action button that codes gives me only

> nil

output. Where i doing mistake any idea ?

Comment: @Vinodh yeah sure model codes true. i think mistake on  request.httpBody = sendingdata.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8); or  if let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData as Data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: AnyObject] {

Comment: @Vinodh also i added login model

Comment: @Vinodh nope still same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128791/discussion-between-vinodh-and-swiftdeveloper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the below code am using which is working fine with local son.Since you haven't provided the url and other details

```
    if let file = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "response", ofType: "json") {
                do {
                    let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: file))
                    let login = try self.getLogin(rawData: jsonData )

                    let arr = login.first

                    if let date = arr?.ServerCurrentDate {

                        print("Comming Date  = \(date)")


                    }

                }
                catch{
                    print(error)
                }
            }


 private func getLogin(rawData: Data) throws -> [Login] {
        var login = [Login]()

        do {
            if let jsonDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: rawData, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: AnyObject] {
                print(jsonDict)
                if let result = jsonDict["Result"] as? [String : AnyObject]
                {
                    var properties = [String: AnyObject]()
                    properties["IsSuccess"] = result["IsSuccess"] as? Bool as AnyObject?
                    properties["MemberId"] = result["MemberId"] as? Int as AnyObject?
                    properties["Name"] = result["Name"] as? String as AnyObject?
                    properties["Image"] = result["Image"] as? String as AnyObject?
                    properties["FacebookId"] = result["FacebookId"] as? Int as AnyObject?
                    properties["FacebookMail"] = result["FacebookMail"] as? String as AnyObject?
                    properties["Phone"] = result["Phone"] as? String as AnyObject?
                    properties["Code"] = result["Code"] as? String as AnyObject?
                    properties["Token"] = result["Token"] as? String as AnyObject?
                    properties["ServerCurrentDate"] = result["ServerCurrentDate"] as? String as AnyObject?
                    let loginget = Login(properties: properties)
                    login.append(loginget)
                }

            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        return login
    }
```

And my local json file

> response.json

```
{
    "Result": {
        "IsSuccess": true,
        "MemberId": 73,
        "Name": "X4r-7a",
        "Image": "MemberImage/48a25240-26a9-46bf-8eb5-72a6b86ad555.png",
        "FacebookId": null,
        "FacebookMail": null,
        "Phone": "0111111112",
        "Code": "5425",
        "Token": "570f4112-0f37-4e23-a2d7-5dad6af9378a",
        "ServerCurrentDate": "2016-11-23-10-41-32"
    }
}
```

Comment: @Vinodth ty man please approve edit. your codes working with real json file but i have server side problem i think.

Comment: you only me gave this response, so i used it.

Answer (score 2):

Your values are one step deeper in the json structure:

```
... 

if let result = jsonDict["Result"] as? [String : AnyObject] 
{
   properties[LoginJsonKeys.Name] = result["Name"] as? String
}
...
```

hope that helps

Comment: yeah true, i added it into my class codes like you show but same result gives nil when output.